# Dynamo DB single partition, Global Secondary indexes

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb

**Current Scenario**

Datastore used: Dynamo Db.

DB size:  15-20 MB

**Problem**: for storing data I am thinking to use a common hash as the partition key (and timestamp as sort key), so that the complete table is saved in a single partition only. This would give me undivided throughput for the table.

But I also intend to create GSIs for querying, so I was wondering whether it would be wrong to use GSIs for single partition. I can use Local SIs also.

Is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, GSI is basically just another DynamoDB table. It follows the same partitioning rules as the main table. Partitions in you primary table are not correlated to the partitions of your GSIs. So it doesn't matter if your table has a single partition or not.

Using single partition in DynamoDB is a bad architectural choice overall, but I would argue that for 20 Mb database that doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 0):

> DynamoDB manages table partitioning for you automatically, adding new
>   partitions if necessary and distributing provisioned throughput
>   capacity evenly across them.

Deciding which partition the item should go can't be controlled if the partition key values are different.

I guess what you are going to do is having same partition key value for all the items with different sort key value (timestamp). In this case, I believe the data will be stored in single partition though **I didn't understand your point regarding undivided throughput**.

If you wanted to keep all the items of the index in **single partition**, I think LSI (Local Secondary Index) would be best suited here. LSI is basically having an alternate sort key for the partition key.

> A local secondary index maintains an alternate sort key for a given
>   partition key value.

Your single partition rule is **not applicable for index** and you wanted different partition key, then you need GSI.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the answer. Firstly, it is dynamo db's policy that it divides the throughput among the partitions. So if i keep all my data in a single partition, I'll get the full throughput . Secondly, what do you mean by "Your single partition rule is not applicable for index and you wanted different partition key, then you need GSI. "

Comment: Welcome. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Firstly, it is dynamo db's policy that it divides the throughput among the partitions. So if i keep all my data in a single partition, I'll get the full throughput . Secondly, what do you mean by "Your single partition rule is not applicable for index and you wanted different partition key, then you need GSI. "

Comment: Refer the data distribution section here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html